# How to echo only Once on Page in Function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, curl

Here is my function:

```
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, function ( $resource, $download_size, $downloaded_size, $upload_size, $uploaded_size) use ($array)
{
static $previousProgress = 0;

    if ( $download_size == 0 ) {
        $progress = 0;
    } else {
        $progress = round( $downloaded_size * 100 / $download_size );
    }
```

As you can see I'm inserting my own variables with `use` at the end of the function.

What I'm trying to do is simply echo this line ONCE after the `else` condition

```
echo ' ' . $progress . '%' . ' (' . bytes($downloaded_size) . ' of ' . bytes($download_size) . ') ';
```

I've tried things such as

```
static $previousProgress = 0;
$count = $previousProgress++;

    } else {
    if ($count == 1) { echo echo ' ' . $progress . '%' . ' (' . bytes($downloaded_size) . ' of ' . bytes($download_size) . ') '; }
        $progress = round( $downloaded_size * 100 / $download_size );
    }
```

But at this point the function has already ran an unknown amount of times (50, or 60 sometimes), before it hits the `else` condition.

I can of course do this

```
static $previousProgress = 0;
    $count = $previousProgress++;
    if ($count == 1) { echo ' ' . $progress . '%' . ' (' . bytes($downloaded_size) . ' of ' . bytes($download_size) . ') '; }
```

And it works to only echo once.. but the issue is `CURL` does not have the `$downloaded_size` or `$download_size` variables set and display as `0 bytes` - therefore it needs to be in the else condition.

I've tried using `true` / `false` variables as one would normally do to output something once in a `for` or `foreach` loop, but since the function is just recursively running until it times out, the function starts over again and this does not work.

As I said, I can insert an array of variables into this function to help me... but I'm not sure how I can do this considering the function starts over and is re-run everytime..

Tried other random things but I am apparently missing something.  How can I echo the download size only once in the repeating function?

Comment: Why do you think the function is recursive? It's called periodically by `curl`, but it doesn't call itself (how could it, it doesn't even have a name?).

Comment: Why do you want to print only once? Isn't the point of a progress function to keep updating the percentage as the download continues?

Comment: Good point.. it only seems recursive.  Sorry I am still learning the syntax.  I am trying to echo once the full download size in bytes, then using javascript to change the value of a <progress> indicator which has no text associated with it... (didn't include because I didn't think it was relevant to the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static boolean variable should do what you want.

```
static $firstTime = true;
if ($firstTime) {
    echo "something";
    $firstTime = false;
}
```

The problem with your code is probably because you were using post-increment. If `$previousProgress` is `0`, the line:

```
$count = $previousProgress++;
```

will set `$count` to `0` (the old value) while incrementing `$previousProgress` to `1`. So the `if ($count == 1)` condition wasn't true until the *second* iteration. 
If you used `++$previousProgress` it would set them both to `1`. That's the difference between pre-increment and post-increment.

Comment: Works perfect ! Thank you.

Comment: See my update for why your code probably wasn't working.